# How to loop every two seconds

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I'm having problem with my ColdFusion code.

I am trying to write some code that loops only every 2 seconds. I tried using `cfloop` and looping over a date or time range. But this does not solve my problem. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Don't know ColdFusion, JavaScript fundamentally doesn't support delaying inside a loop. You need to schedule a callback function to be called periodically.

Comment: JavaScript has [**window.setInterval**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) method which calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function. Use it similar to this: `setInterval(function(){..}, 2000);`

Comment: As @Potatoswatter said, instead of thinking in terms of a loop, you might want to have a built-in timer or a roll-your-own timer function (see: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_e-g_64.html ) that is used to keep time. Something checks that timer, and then calls a function every 2 seconds. That function will do everything in the loop you originally mentioned. You could put that construct inside a while loop that runs continuously while some flag is true.

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Maybe back up a little and explain your overall goal (in plain english) first. Because from what little you have described it is unclear whether you are asking about client or server side operations.

Comment: Give your code snippet . you can use sleep() within cfquery tag.

Answer (score 2):

you can solve this problem using loop also. all you need to do is just write a index loop with proper steps  for example you can refer this code.

```
  <cfset startTime = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,5,10)>
  <cfset endTime = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,5,20)>
  <cfloop from="#startTime#" to="#endTime#" index="i" step="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,0,2)#">
         Hello World! <br />
   </cfloop>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [`sleep`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6f29.html) function. You can either call it in CFML:

```
  <!--- 2 second delay --->
  <cfset sleep(2000) />
```

or from CFScript (Ecmascript/Javascript notation):

```
  sleep(2000);
```

There should be lots of sleep examples available.